# how to make directory downloadable in IIS

Tags: download, webserver, iis, vps, directory-listing

I have 75GB of data on my Windows VPS. I need to download the directory containing 75 GB of data on my local system.

FTP should not work in such a large amount of data.

What I have done is,

I have created one website in the IIS and set the path of the directory containing 75 GB of data.  Then, I have enabled Directory browsing.

Next, I have added the host entry in my local system using the domain name and the IP address which I created in IIS.

Now the problem is that I can access all the data via browser, but cannot download it.

Any solution would be grateful.

Comment: My experience is that any readable data is also downloadable. What kind of a problem are you encountering?

Comment: What's the problem with FTP, exactly?

Comment: FTP can not work for such large files, it time out's each time.

Comment: I want to download the entire director, but I can not see any option to download that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.